# How to solve for modulus

Tags: inequality

For the following formulae

```
(x mod 10)*4==17
(x mod 10)*4!=17
```

How to solve x for above formulae?

Comment: Do you mean $4x = 17 \pmod{10}$ and $4x \neq 17 \pmod{10}$?

Comment: This is impossible: There is no entity which is equal to 17 and not equal to 17 at the same time.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks, but what i mean is these formulae holds individually...I have been told that a SMT solver cannot solve these equations, but they seem to be solvable?

Comment: @DylanSp no really, that does not seem to be what I mean...it is exactly the formulae in question, which holds independently.

Comment: What's the domain of $x$; are we considering integer $x$ or real $x$?

Comment: All integer $x$ will give $4x \not \equiv 17 \pmod {10}$ or even 
if you have an unusal view on mod $4(x \bmod 10) \ne 17$